# regexp to extract multiple occurrences of a pattern in a string

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, hive

I'm running hive 0.13.
I have a column that has various strings that look like this:

`a:ABC,b:SDSD,c:213123#a:SDS,b:UIOU,c:89797#a:TYRQQQW,b:UIOUIOYYO,c:546654
a:DFSS,b:TYRTTN,c:12323#a:HJH,b:YTUUUTYUTYT,c:67890
a:TYY,b:OPIUIU,c:86768`

They could of any length, one set a,b,c values will always be separated by a '#'.

Now, what I'm trying to do is, extract only the b column, like:

`b:SDSD,b:UIOU,b:UIOUIOYYO
b:TYRTTN,b:YTUUUTYUTYT`

What I've been trying to do is something like
`regexp_replace(column,'^channel:+[A-Z]{3,10},',")`

I.e., replace all values that isn't b:... with blank, but this isn't working.

Could someone please correct me or suggest a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[^b]:[^,]*,?
```

Try this.Replace by `empty space`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/27

Comment: Thanks for this.
But how would you approach this if, in place of a,b & c, we had words.
Say 'a' was supplier,'b' was agent and 'c' was player.

Comment: @FenderBender you can use `negative lookahead` `^((?!agent).)*`

Comment: Thanks.
A slightly different version of this worked for me.
But you certainly got me thinking in the right direction.

Comment: @FenderBender can you please share what worked for you